# Disable numeric validation on client side jquery.validate

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

Is it possible to disable "The field must be a number" validation message when using Validation Attributes in C#? I only need to disable the validation on the client side.

Comment: put your .aspx and .cs what u did ?

Answer (score 0):

After all the validation scripts are called on page add something akin to:

```
$('#MyNumberField').rules('remove', 'number');
```

Comment: I replaced #MyNumberField with the id of my field and put the function in document.ready, but it did not seem to work. Would I need to change anything else?

Comment: My mistake...it worked it just didn't show in the page source